# RegEx: Why start a comma-delimited string with a comma?

Tags: regex, arrays, string, mongodb, csv

I was reading up on [how to model tree structures in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) and came across [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) in which a comma-delimited path string is illustrated. In the example, the string starts with a comma and I was wondering if there was a reason or benefit for doing that apposed to just having a comma after each item in the list?

The reason I marked this post as specific to RegEx is, in Java I would not want a comma at the beginning because I would parse the string into an array using...

`String[] array = string.split(",");`

...and in PHP I would use...

`$array = explode(",", $string);`

In either of those cases, starting the string with a comma would result in an empty string at `$array[0]`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is not using a `split` type function rather its doing something that involves looking at characters in a string.

The "guard" leading delimiter is so that if you wanted to find the single entry `aaa` in:

```
",zzzaaa,bbb,aaa,zzz"
```

you can search for `,aaa,` thus avoiding a false match of `zzzaaa` if you searched for `aaa,`.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier on the index to regex than conditionally doing `/^[^,]SomeTopic,*`

Comment: This will fail if the first item is `SomeTopic, ...` and will pass if there is `CSomeTopic` where `C` is a random character. Using regex, you only need to specify the begin `^` and then check if there is a comma `(?=,)`, all in one you get `/^SomeTopic(?=,)/`. To search for it anywhere you might use `/^SomeTopic(?=,)|(?<=,)SomeTopic(?=,)|(?<=,)SomeTopic(?=$)/`

Comment: @HamZa That last regex definitely wouldn't use an index

Comment: Oh forgot to mention if the platform supports lookaround assertions.

Comment: I got a bit carried away, but it seems that [MongoDB uses PCRE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) so it should work

Comment: @HamZa indeed the problem comes with index usage, only specific regexes can use indexes when they are used in specific ways

Answer (score 1):

In your referenced article, this has a benefit, because the regex `/,Programming,/` is used. It simply searches for words that have a comma before **and** after the word. In case you leave the comma at the beginning of the string out, you'd additionally need to handle this issue, because `Programming,` would not be found by the RegEx.